# How to fetch groups ordered by aggregative value, using jooq

Tags: java, group-by, grouping, aggregate-functions, jooq

I want to implement this query using jooq:

```
SELECT bank_id, array_agg(id)
FROM aggregative_line_item
GROUP BY bank_id
ORDER BY sum(amount) desc;
```

Now, jooq provides fetchGroups(), that perfectly maps values to the Map<String, List>

```
 create.selectFrom(aggregative_line_item)
            .fetchGroups(aggregative_line_item.bank_id, aggregative_line_item.id);
```

However, I don't understand how to order the returned results by sum() value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use [`ResultQuery.fetchGroups()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchGroups(org.jooq.Field,org.jooq.Field)), then you're grouping result sets in Java, not in SQL. There are a lot of legitimate cases for this, but in your case, I think you should do everything in SQL directly, assuming you're using PostgreSQL, because you already used `ARRAY_AGG()` in your SQL query. Just write:

```java
Result<Record2<String, Integer[]>> result =
create.select(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.BANK_ID, arrayAgg(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.ID))
      .from(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM)
      .groupBy(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.BANK_ID)
      .orderBy(sum(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.AMOUNT).desc())
      .fetch();
```

This assumes the usual static imports, including:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

The result is not exactly in the form you were looking for, but you can still call `fetchMap()` on the result, e.g.

```java
Map<String, Integer[]> map = result.fetchMap(
  AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.BANK_ID, 
  arrayAgg(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.ID)
);
```

Or, instead of repeating the expressions, you could assign them to local variables and reuse them:

```java
Field<String> key = AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.BANK_ID;
Field<Integer[]> value = arrayAgg(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.ID);

// And then:
Map<String, Integer[]> map = 
create.select(key, value)
      .from(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM)
      .groupBy(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.BANK_ID)
      .orderBy(sum(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.AMOUNT).desc())
      .fetchMap(key, value);
```

Still, if you prefer the `List<Integer>` type over the `Integer[]` type, you could use the JDK `Collector` APIs on [`ResultQuery.collect()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)), instead:

```java
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = 
create.select(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.BANK_ID, arrayAgg(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.ID))
      .from(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM)
      .groupBy(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.BANK_ID)
      .orderBy(sum(AGGREGATIVE_LINE_ITEM.AMOUNT).desc())
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
         r -> r.value1(),
         r -> Arrays.asList(r.value2())
      ));
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning the Result#intoGroup() is currently implemented using LinkedHashMap which guaranteed that the initial ordering is kept (of course that's an undocumented implementation detail that might change)

Comment: @AmitGoldstein: Makes sense. It's documented in some places, but not in others. While we won't gurantee the `LinkedHashMap` implementation, we can certainly guarantee the iteration order stability (which is what `LinkedHashMap` happens to do). We'll improve that in the near future: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11154